# How to prevent deadlocks in the following C# code?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, deadlock

The following C# class is used in a multithreaded enviroment. I removed very much of the actual code. The problem occurs when calling MethodA and MethodB almost simultaneously. The order of the lock in the IsDepleted property doesn't solves the problem. Removing lock(WaitingQueue) from the IsDepleted property solves the deadlock, but this solution causes a problem when another thread adds/removes an item from the WaitingQueue between the WaitingQueue.Count == 0 and Processing.Count == 0 statements.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

class Example
{
    bool IsDepleted
    {
        get
        {
            lock (Processing)
            {
                lock (WaitingQueue)
        {
                    return WaitingQueue.Count == 0
             && Processing.Count == 0;
        }
            }
        }
    }

    private readonly List<object> Processing = new List<object>();
    private readonly Queue<object> WaitingQueue = new Queue<object>();

    public void MethodA(object item)
    {
        lock (WaitingQueue)
        {
            if (WaitingQueue.Count > 0)
            {
                if (StartItem(WaitingQueue.Peek()))
                {
                    WaitingQueue.Dequeue();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void MethodB(object identifier)
    {
        lock (Processing)
        {
            Processing.Remove(identifier);
            if (!IsDepleted)
            {
                return;
            }
        }
    //Do something...
    }

    bool StartItem(object item)
    {
        //Do something and return a value
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends if you want a quick fix or a rigorous fix.

A quick fix would be just to use one lock object in all cases.

e.g. `private readonly object _lock = new object();`

And then just lock on that. However, depending on your situation, that may impact performance more than you can accept.

I.e. your code would become this:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

class Example
{
    private readonly object _lock = new object();

    bool IsDepleted
    {
        get
        {
            lock (_lock)
            {
                return WaitingQueue.Count == 0
                 && Processing.Count == 0;
            }
        }
    }

    private readonly List<object> Processing = new List<object>();
    private readonly Queue<object> WaitingQueue = new Queue<object>();

    public void MethodA(object item)
    {
        lock (_lock)
        {
            if (WaitingQueue.Count > 0)
            {
                if (StartItem(WaitingQueue.Peek()))
                {
                    WaitingQueue.Dequeue();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void MethodB(object identifier)
    {
        lock (_lock)
        {
            Processing.Remove(identifier);
            if (!IsDepleted)
            {
                return;
            }
        }
        //Do something...
    }

    bool StartItem(object item)
    {
        //Do something and return a value
    }
}
```

Comment: And the non-quick fix would be?

Comment: Perform a detailed analysis of the lock usage throughout the program and choose a more appropriate locking scheme.

Answer (score 3):

Take the Processing lock in method A and the WaitingQueue lock in method B (in other words, make it look like the first block of code). That way, you always take the locks in the same order and you'll never deadlock.

Comment: In that case, there is no need to have two locks. :)

Comment: If your going to do that then your always doign a double lock and you might as well just simplify it to one lock

Comment: Locking mutexes in the same order is an absolute must to prevent deadlocks.  The required lock-ordering does _not_ imply that one always only needs one lock. Using several mutexes may improve the performance, if done right.

Comment: @gimpf Not based on the provided sample though... I suppose if the locks are being used individually elsewhere in the codebase there may be an impact, but if not, then it's just unneccesary overhead.

Answer (score 2):

Simplify your code and use only a single object to lock on. You could also replace your locks with:

Monitor.TryEnter(Processing,1000)

this will give you a 1 second timeout. So essentially:

```
        if (Monitor.TryEnter(Processing, 1000))
        {
            try
            {
                //do x
            }
            finally
            {
                Monitor.Exit(Processing);
            }
        }
```

Now you won't stop the deadlock but you can handle the case where you don't get a lock.

Comment: best way to prevent deadlock is avoid locking resource at all. If you need to protect a critical region like that... the monitor approach is a good solution. Nice one!